# jQuery to change value of bootstrap-slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML slider script for making a **Bootstrap** slider:

```
<div class="slider-div">
     <input id="ex19" type="text"
          data-provide="slider"
          data-slider-ticks="[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]"
          data-slider-ticks-labels='["0mm", "1mm", "2mm", "3mm", "4mm", "5mm", "6mm", "7mm", "8mm", "9mm"]'
          data-slider-min="1"
          data-slider-max="9"
          data-slider-step="1"
          data-slider-value="0"
          data-slider-tooltip="hide"
     />
</div>
```

A template can be seen on *Example 19* of this [Bootstrap-slider page](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/).

How can I manually change the slider via **jQuery**?

I noticed that when a new point is chosen on the slider, there is a lot of **HTML** and **CSS** content that changes, too. This means that I can't simply do something like

```
$('.slider-handle').attr('aria-valuenow', 7);
```

because all that does is change the literal value but nothing visually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read [**documentation**](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#functions) first and after that, use `setValue` function:

```
$('#ex19').slider('setValue', 7);
```

Comment: No need to be snarky